# Improving Google Maps Performance

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to draw about 10000 line on Google Maps. So, it is spending too much time in `draw()` method. Moving on map becomes very laggy. Is there any way to cache drawing or can I draw just the part of map / canvas which is currently seen on screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I can draw all 10000 lines without any lag. It is all about designing `draw()` method carefully. I moved some object creating operations (like Path, Point) out of draw(). I saw that especially `projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);` is very expensive operation. Finally I set an alpha constant which holds the pixel value of finger movement. And it only draws when pixelX or pixelY movement is bigger than alpha.

Answer (score 2):

drawing 10000 lines will never get lag free. I'm guessing you connect points.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447350/android-maps-point-clustering/7447998#7447998) is an implementation of point Clustering in mapView and also renders the visible ones if you want. So you can draw lines to the clustered points.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post, it suggests drawing your lines into a shape then drawing that to the mapview.

Here: [Cache whats being draw on MapView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677961/cache-whats-being-draw-on-mapview-in-android)

Just a suggestion on this one, you may want to try saving the MapView as a bitmap then render that instead (depending on your situation).

Here: [Save MapView as a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221098/save-mapview-as-a-bitmap)